# How to convert a dictionary to a list based on an order in the dictionary value

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a dictionary like this:

```
>>> d
{'c': {'icecream': 'orange', 'fruit': 'apple', 'size': 1},'a': {'foo': 'bar', 'something': 'else', 'size': 0}, 'd': {'computer': 'mac', 'size': -1}}
```

How can I order the elements of this dictionary by `size` with the exception that item with `size` `-1` comes in the end.

So the above dictionary would turn to:

```
>>> converted
{'a': {'foo': 'bar', 'something': 'else', 'size': 0}, 'c': {'icecream': 'orange', 'fruit': 'apple', 'size': 1}, 'd': {'computer': 'mac', 'size': -1}}
```

**Update**

Since dictionaries can not be ordered.

Is it possible to convert the above to a list with dictionary? i.e.

```
>>> converted_to_list
[{'foo': 'bar', 'something': 'else', 'size': 0}, {'icecream': 'orange', 'fruit': 'apple', 'size': 1}, {'computer': 'mac', 'size': -1}]
```

Comment: Gah, that is by Key, you actually want the "by value" question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value   Answer is the same though: Dictionaries can't be sorted. Look at `OrderedDict`

Comment: Is it possible to convert it to a list based on size element?

Comment: Ordinary dictionaries can't be order. You need to use a [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead.

Comment: @Andy I updated the question. I don't think it is a duplicate any longer

Comment: What if you had `"size":-3` in another dict?

Comment: Dictionaries cannot be ordered or indexed, since its a collection of key-value-pair

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `OrderedDict`

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = {'c': {'icecream': 'orange', 'fruit': 'apple', 'size': 1},'a': {'foo': 'bar', 'something': 'else', 'size': 0}, 'd': {'computer': 'mac', 'size': -1}}

print (OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]['size'] if t[1]['size']>=0 else float("inf") )))
```

As you want `-1` to be the last one, just set the key to infinite (`float["inf"]`) in this case.

Comment: `if t[1]['size'] >= 0` or your order will be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary is unordered. That means you can not sort it and keep it in order.

However, if you wish to iterate it in order (as a list containing tuple of the key and value), you can use this:

```
>>> d = {'c': {'icecream': 'orange', 'fruit': 'apple', 'size': 1},'a': {'foo': 'bar', 'something': 'else', 'size': 0}, 'd': {'computer': 'mac', 'size': -1}}
>>> sorted = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['size'])
>>> sorted
[('d', {'computer': 'mac', 'size': -1}), ('a', {'something': 'else', 'foo': 'bar', 'size': 0}), ('c', {'fruit': 'apple', 'icecream': 'orange', 'size': 1})]
```

You can easily transform this list into a dictionary back, by creating a dictionary and adding all of this values:

```
>>> g = {}
>>> for x in sorted:
...     g[x[0]] = x[1]
...
>>> g
{'d': {'size': -1, 'computer': 'mac'}, 'a': {'something': 'else', 'size': 0, 'foo': 'bar'}, 'c': {'fruit': 'apple', 'icecream': 'orange', 'size': 1}}
```

Answer (score -1):

Python dictionaries are unordered.

Use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead.